# How can I remove this annoying message: "Failed to find cgroup2 mount"?

Tags: io-redirection, stderr, ss

I run this command

```
ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
Failed to find cgroup2 mount
.....
```

I tried with 2> /dev/null...

```
 ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127 2> /dev/null
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    Failed to find cgroup2 mount
    .....
```

How to avoid the annoying message about cgroup2 mount?
Distro is Slackware 15.0

Comment: The `cgroup2` virtual filesystem is meant to be mounted on `/sys/fs/cgroup`, systemd takes care of that on systems that use it. Maybe you need to do it via `/etc/fstab` on Slackware?

Comment: I'd say that's *maybe* a bug in `ss` (iproute2) – as long as it only uses cgroups for looking up some auxiliary info, it should not assume that cgroups are in use on the system at all, rather than complaining.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have your redirection at the wrong point in the pipeline. Presumably the error comes from the `ss` command, so that is where you should hide the error output. Or you can group the output and redirect from the command as a whole.

Here are some possible solutions to suppress any errors:

Redirect the standard error of the command producing the messages:

```
ss -tulpnoea 2> /dev/null|grep -i water|grep -v 127
```

Run the commands in a subshell and redirect the standard error of the subshell:

```
(ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127) 2> /dev/null
```

Group the commands and redirect the standard error of the group:

```
{ ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127 ; } 2> /dev/null
```

Or if you specifically want to suppress that error and not others (subject to shell support)

```
ss -tulpnoea 2> >(grep -Fxv 'Failed to find cgroup2 mount' >&2)|grep -i water|grep -v 127)
```

```
(ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127) 2> >(grep -Fxv 'Failed to find cgroup2 mount' >&2)
```

```
{ ss -tulpnoea|grep -i water|grep -v 127 ; } 2> >(grep -Fxv 'Failed to find cgroup2 mount' >&2)
```